# PostgreSQL Change owner of all tables under a specific schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am trying to change the owner of all tables under the same schema in one command line. i.e: `alter table schema_name.* owner to newowner`. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 49):

## Reassigned Owned

There is a specific privilege command that does just this, [`RESASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html). This reassigns all objects, not just ones in a specific schema.

## Schema-specific

You can generate the `ALTER TABLE` commands with the following,

```
SELECT format(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I OWNER TO %I;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  current_user  -- or another just put it in quotes
)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mySchema';
```

In psql, you can run them by following it immediately with `\gexec`

Comment: To make it clear, `\gexec` should be in the line of the `WHERE` clause, right after the semi-colon.

Comment: Is it wise to reassign the `postgres` user to `user` then? Because maybe `postgres` must be the only owner of some specific parts of the database, that you probably don't want `user` to be the owner...

Answer (score 23):

If you can query the tablenames in your schema, you can generate the queries to ALTER table ownership.

For example:

```
 select 'ALTER TABLE ' || t.tablename || ' OWNER TO new_owner;' 
 from  pg_tables t
 where t.tableowner != 'rdsadmin';
```

will return the query to change ownership of all tables:

```
ALTER TABLE schema_version OWNER TO ali;
ALTER TABLE users OWNER TO ali; 
ALTER TABLE company OWNER TO ali;
ALTER TABLE books OWNER TO ali;
...
```

then you can just run these :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of any way to accomplish this purely through psql, but using bash, you can list the tables in database $DB with:

```
psql -tc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = '${SCHEMA}';" ${DB}
```

And the ownership can be transferred to $OWNER with:

```
psql -c "alter table ${SCHEMA}.${table} owner to ${OWNER}" ${DB}
```

Stringing this together gives you:

```
 $ for table in `psql -tc "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = '${SCHEMA}';" ${DB}` ; do  psql -c "alter table ${SCHEMA}.${table} owner to ${OWNER}" ${DB} ; done
```

$DB, $SCHEMA and $OWNER represent the database, schema (usually 'public') and the new owner's name respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to above using bash but I had to output in a text file and then input into psql:

```
$ psql -qAt -d mydatabase -c "SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '||schemaname||'.'||tablename||' \
                                      OWNER TO new_owner;' \
                                      FROM pg_tables \
                                      WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'" > data.txt


$ psql < data.txt -d mydatabase
```

Based on this, but database added: http://penningpence.blogspot.ca/2014/09/changing-owner-of-multiple-database.html

Answer (score 1):

This script will do the trick.

`sh change_owner.sh  -n new_owner -S schema_name`

`sh change_owner.sh -n user1 -S public`

```
Summary:
    Tables/Sequences/Views : 16
    Functions              : 43
    Aggregates             : 1
    Type                   : 2
```

found here https://github.com/trrao/PostgreSQL_Scripts

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I use for changing table, view and function ownership in a schema.  It is fast, clean and a good example of how to use cursors as well.
Also, no command line required.

The following will change permissions through a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YOURSCHEMA.do_changeowner(
    newowner text,
    pschem text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
  tblnames CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
    WHERE schemaname = pschem;
  viewnames CURSOR FOR
    SELECT viewname FROM pg_views
    WHERE schemaname = pschem;
  funcnames CURSOR FOR
    SELECT p.proname AS name, pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid) as params
    FROM pg_proc p 
    JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace 
    WHERE n.nspname = pschem;

begin

  FOR stmt IN tblnames LOOP
    EXECUTE 'alter TABLE ' || pschem || '.' || stmt.tablename || ' owner to ' || newowner || ';';
  END LOOP;
  FOR stmt IN viewnames LOOP
    EXECUTE 'alter VIEW ' || pschem || '.' || stmt.viewname || ' owner to ' || newowner || ';';
  END LOOP;
  FOR stmt IN funcnames LOOP
    EXECUTE 'alter FUNCTION ' || pschem || '.' || stmt.name || '(' ||  stmt.params || ') owner to ' || newowner || ';';
  END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```